# Objective-C if ([self isKindOfClass: ... ]) static method

Tags: objective-c, categories, static-methods

I seek help in understanding why code behaves so strange. What I have: `BaseClass : NSManagedObject` and `ChildClass : BaseClass`

BaseClass has a category. .h:

```
@interface BaseClass (Category)

+ (NSArray)method;

@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation BaseClass (Category)

+ (NSArray *)method
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[ChildClass class]) {
        do stuff
        return resultArray;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

From another place in project I call `*array = [ChildClass method];`. In the BaseClass (Category) implementation console reads `self = (Class)ChildClass`, but still the execution flow skips the `if` and passes right to `return nil;` for some reason, that is beyond my understanding. Any suggestions why that may be? All answers are appreciated. Thanks.

... as I don't have enough rep points, I'm not posting the screenshots. Hope I was clear.

Comment: My guess is that when you call `[ChildClass method]`, it's not called on an *instance* of `ChildClass`, but on the class itself. (Classes being objects in ObjC.) A class is not an instance of itself.

Comment: You're using Coredata so can you confirm that in your object model you have base a BaseClass and a ChildClass AND the ChildClass is set with BaseClass as its parent entity?

Comment: To complement what @millimoose said, you can, instead of comparing via isKindOfClass, use the `self` object itself, which is the class it was called on in this scenario.

Comment: `if (self == [ChildClass class])`

Comment: "Strange behaviour" is not very descriptive.

Comment: @Rog yes, in the model they are child-parent, both classes were generated by core data as they are.

Comment: @millimoose and Richard J. Ross III i should have thought of that. Sounds very probable. Thanks, but i will have to check that tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in a static method, so self represents the class itself. Is enough to do this:

```
if (self==[ChildClass class]) {
    do stuff
    return resultArray;
}
```

Comment: Yep. I get it now, thanks everyone answered for clearing me out on this. Cant vote up the answer just yet though :)).

Comment: You might want to check out [`+[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBJIDAB).

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off doing `[[childOrBaseInstance class] method];` in your code that is calling `+method`.

`ChildClass` would have it's own `+method` that override's `BaseClass`'s `+method`.

Any time you check your class and do something different, ask yourself if you're just manually recreating polymorphism.